# Use VBScript to open an application and perform actions in it

Tags: vbscript

I've written the following vbs to open ciphergraph:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\CipherGraph\LaunchStub.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing
WScript.Sleep 250
```

I'd like to also select the 'Connect' button in the ciphergraph window - I can get to it by hitting 'TAB' twice and then 'RETURN' when the app launches

how do I do this? Sorry if it's a basic question, new to VBS, but can't find an answer??

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WshShell object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99(v=vs.84).aspx) is the solution.

*- Use its [`AppActivate()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek(v=vs.84).aspx) to bring any running application into the foreground.*

*- Use its [`SendKeys()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx) to send keystrokes to whatever application currently has the focus.*

**This is so simple that I omit sample code (you're almost there yourself, after all).**

Answer (score 0):

I think this works better:

```
If Input = "youtube" Or Input = "Youtube" Then
    Sapi.speak "Opening Youtube"
    wshShell.run "www.youtube.com"
End If
```

It even opens websites!